# React Router - How to render "/:id" route within a layout route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to render a route with `"/:id"` inside a Layout route as documentation shows in https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#layout-routes, but it always renders `<Apps>` component.

Here's the layout:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <ErrorBoundary>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="admin" element={<Admin />} />
      <Route element={<AdminLayout />}>
        <Route path="admin/apps" element={<Apps />} />
        <Route
          path="admin/apps/:id/artifacts"
          element={<ArtifactsAdmin />}
        />
        <Route
          path="admin/apps/:id/version"
          element={<Version />}
        />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </ErrorBoundary>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I also tried to put the two routes with `":id"` inside the `"/admin/apps"` element but then I'm getting a warning that no route is matching.

What is the correct approach to do it?

I was expecting to render `<ArtifactsAdmin>` and `<Version>` when url changes but it always renders `<Apps>`.

Comment: What URL path are you trying to access? Something like `"/admin/admin/apps/someIdValue/[artifacts|version]"`? I don't see any issues with the code you have shared. Can you [edit] to clarify what the issue is in better detail and what any reproduction steps are to produce the issue?

Comment: Im tying to acces "/admin/apps/someIdValue/[artifacts|version]" also notice that the first route is not  inside the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nested routes are injecting an additional `"admin"` path segment in the matchable paths. If you would like to match and render nested route `"/admin/apps/*"` then remove the additional `"admin"` segment.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <ErrorBoundary>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/admin">
        <Route index element={<Admin />} />  // <-- "/admin"
        <Route path="apps" element={<AdminLayout />}>
          <Route index element={<Apps />} /> // <-- "/admin/apps"
          <Route path=":id">
            <Route
              path="artifacts"               // <-- "/admin/apps/:id/artifacts"
              element={<ArtifactsAdmin />}
            />
            <Route
              path="version"                 // <-- "/admin/apps/:id/version"
              element={<Version />}
            />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </ErrorBoundary>
</BrowserRouter>
```

[image: Edit react-router-how-to-render-id-route-within-a-layout-route]

Comment: Thanks ! Saddly it doesnt resolve the issue, I've tried to implement the routing as you show but still not working. I also tried to navigate to `"/admin/admin/apps/someIdValue/[artifacts|version]"` with my code example but no route was matched

Comment: @JuanAttorri It should work for you. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-how-to-render-id-route-within-a-layout-route-ncvhc5) demo. I've also added the link to my answer.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much, I was not using the Outlet component.